# reorder factor level and apply the new order to original data

Tags: r

Currently I have df data with 3 column.

```
sizes <- factor(c("small", "large", "large", "small", "medium"))
c <- sample(1:5)
a <- c("M","M","F","M","F")
df <- data.frame(sizes,c,a)
> head(df$sizes)
[1] small  large  large  small  medium
Levels: large medium small

> head(df)
       sizes c a
    1  small 1 M
    2  large 3 M
    3  large 4 F
    4  small 5 M
    5 medium 2 F
```

I am trying to reorder the factor data sizes as "small", "medium", "large" and apply it back to the df.

Once I apply

```
sizes <- factor(sizes, levels = c("small", "medium", "large"))
sizes
[1] small  large  large  small  medium
Levels: small medium large
```

But my original data set still not reorder

```
> head(df$sizes)
[1] small  large  large  small  medium
Levels: large medium small
```

Anyone helps?

Comment: Did you only reorder `sizes` and not `df$sizes`?

Comment: Thank you, i don't know what i was thinking!

Comment: @Pascal df$sizes <- factor(df$sizes, levels = c("small", "medium", "large")) it works

Comment: answer posted but don't know how to close it @akrun

Comment: I meant to answer it so that it will not be in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

We specify the `levels` in the `factor` to reorder.

```
 df$sizes <- factor(df$sizes, levels = c("small", "medium", "large"))
```